# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, list, class, model-view-controller, indexing

I am new in generic collections

I have one class .The class name is `ReportSubCategoryModel`

these are that class properties

```
public class ReportSubCategoryModel
    {

        public string ReporTitle { get; set; }
        public string ReporStatus { get; set; }
        public string ReportDescription { get; set; }
        public int ReporSubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public IList<ReportSubCategoryModel> ReportSubCategoryModelList { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to set the lot of values in this class properties from database . So i assigned a list of that class

```
 IList<ReportSubCategoryModel> reportSubCategoryModel = new List<ReportSubCategoryModel>();
```

Now I want to set a values inside of for loop

```
IList<ReportSubCategory> reportSubCategory = datamodel.ReportSubCategory.Where(r => r.ReportCategoryId == reportCategoryId).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < reportSubCategory.Count; i++)
            {
                int reportSubCategoryId = reportSubCategory[i].ReportSubCategoryId;
                ReportStatu reportStatus =
                    datamodel.ReportStatus.SingleOrDefault(
                        r => r.ReportSubCategoryId == reportSubCategoryId);
                if (reportStatus == null)
                {
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportDescription = "Dis";**//This line threw the error**
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReporStatus = "Not Available";
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReporTitle = reportSubCategory[i].ReportSubCategoryName;
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportSubCategoryModelList.Add(reportSubCategoryModel[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportDescription = "Dis";
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReporStatus = "Available For " + reportStatus.ReportStatusDescription;
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReporTitle = reportSubCategory[i].ReportSubCategoryName;
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReporSubCategoryId = reportSubCategoryId;
                    reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportSubCategoryModelList.Add(reportSubCategoryModel[i]);
                }

            }
            return reportSubCategoryModel.ToList();
```

But it's not working.

This line `reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportDescription = "Dis";` give's the error for Index **was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**

You can see this  problem and my code from below image.Please zoom your browser (cntrl+Up Mouse Scrolling)
[image]

how can  i solve this problem ?

Comment: Your `for` loop is based on the `reportSubCategory` array, whilst you then index out of other arrays. If the array sizes do not match, you run the risk of attempting to index elements that do not exist. In this case, it appears that `reportSubCategoryModel` is smaller than `reportSubCategory`. Without understanding what exactly you are triyng to do, it's difficult to offer any refactored code.

Comment: The now-deleted comment about calling `Add` instead of attempting to index items may be relevant. Your `reportSubCategoryModel` list, if empty, should be populated by building a new model then calling `reportSubCategoryModel.Add(model)`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Okay. i understand . but How can i set values in my class?

Comment: I've amended your code in my answer, but I'm not entirely sure if it is what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the whole logic is meant to be, but this is how I feel the code should look like:

```
IList<ReportSubCategory> reportSubCategory = datamodel.ReportSubCategory
    .Where(r => r.ReportCategoryId == reportCategoryId)
    .ToList();

foreach (var subCategory in reportSubCategory)
{
    int reportSubCategoryId = subCategory.ReportSubCategoryId;

    ReportStatus reportStatus = datamodel.ReportStatus
        .SingleOrDefault(r => r.ReportSubCategoryId == reportSubCategoryId);

    if (reportStatus == null)
    {
        var model = new ReportSubCategoryModel();

        model.ReportDescription = "Dis";
        model.ReporStatus = "Not Available";
        model.ReporTitle = subCategory.ReportSubCategoryName;

        // Not sure what this is.
        //model.ReportSubCategoryModelList.Add(reportSubCategoryModel[i]);

        reportSubCategoryModel.Add(model);
    }
    else
    {
        var model = new ReportSubCategoryModel();

        model.ReportDescription = "Dis";
        model.ReporStatus = "Available For " + reportStatus.ReportStatusDescription;
        model.ReporTitle = subCategory.ReportSubCategoryName;
        model.ReporSubCategoryId = reportSubCategoryId;

        // Not sure what this is either.
        //reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportSubCategoryModelList.Add(reportSubCategoryModel[i]);

        reportSubCategoryModel.Add(model);
    }
}

return reportSubCategoryModel;
```

Basically, you `new` up a model, set the properties and then `Add` that to the model list; based on iterating the sub category list.

However, I'm not sure what the whole nested list thing is about (the code I commented out).

Also, this code can be further trimmed, but I'll leave that out for now so as not to depart too much from the provided code.

Comment: But I get new  build error @Adam  

**'SchoolBreifcase.Models.ReportSubCategoryModel' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'SchoolBreifcase.Models.ReportSubCategoryModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @user2419563 That is because you are trying to call `Add` on your own type. In my code, I am calling `Add` on `reportSubCategoryModel`, which in your provided code is an `IList<ReportSubCategoryModel>`.

Comment: sorry for that. Now i will try your way. wait just a mins

Comment: @user2419563 No problem. You need to view Lists as flexible arrays. You very rarely need to talk to the indexer on those. They have `Add` and `Remove` methods for adding / removing, and you can `foreach` to iterate over them.

Comment: But var model = new ReportSubCategoryModel(); this line create more time object ! So Is this line removed my previous foreach value ..??

Comment: @user2419563 I'm not sure what you were trying to do. Do you want to update a model if you find it again?

Comment: I want to add many  values in one List class .So i used that forloop !

Comment: @user2419563 Yeah in that case I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. I've solved the immediate problem of you previously trying to index an element that didn't exist. I'd start a new question for further logic issues.

Comment: Your code is working very good for me !!!!! Thanks ... it's really amazing work . i think i am a lucky man !!

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested loop with in your main loop.With reportSubCategoryModel.Count.

Answer (score 0):

you are treating list as an array.

something similar to following could replace the assigning section

```
var temp = new ReportSubCategoryModel();
temp.ReportDescription  = "dis"; 
....
reportSubCategoryModel.Add(temp);
```

should sort the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have only created the list of reportSubCategoryModel and not yet populated it.

A list does not pre-populate with empty values and will therefore have a length of zero after initialisation. If you with to add new values you need to create your ReportSubCategoryModel object and then add it to the List.

Instead of trying to edit the values of the list;

```
 reportSubCategoryModel[i].ReportDescription = "Dis";
```

Create the ReportSubCategoryModel object first, fill the data and the use the List.Add method to add it to your List.

```
ReportSubCategoryModel reportSubCategoryModelObject = new ReportSubCategoryModel();
reportSubCategoryModelObject.ReportDescription = "Dis";**//This line threw the error**
reportSubCategoryModelObject.ReporStatus = "Not Available";
reportSubCategoryModelObject.ReporTitle = reportSubCategory[i].ReportSubCategoryName;
reportSubCategoryModel.Add(reportSubCategoryModelObject);
```